# Getting 403 forbidden exception while installing jenkins in centos

Tags: linux, jenkins, centos

while trying to execute the following command in centos I am getting the below error  . what I am trying to do is to install jenkins in the centos. can some one help on this. Below is the code snipper I am trying to excute

```
 [vagrant@testbox01 scripts]$ !su
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
--2019-02-22 06:31:53--  http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo
Resolving pkg.jenkins-ci.org (pkg.jenkins-ci.org)... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to pkg.jenkins-ci.org (pkg.jenkins-ci.org)|52.202.51.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2019-02-22 06:31:53 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: Have you tried retrieving it from a mirror? like https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo

Comment: What is this `!su` on the begin of your code? Use command with only `sudo .....`

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is the command(!su) to search previously executed command and execute the same command again for example if we execute commands  sudo .....,cd... ,ls .. sequentially and we want execute sudo command again then we need to use the following command !(search string )

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access internet?

Comment: @cody I tried with this link and able to download jenkins thank you pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a multitude of reasons why you may be getting a 403 on this request. Try an alternate Jenkins mirror for the resource, like:

```
https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can just create the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo` instead of downloading that and put below content in it.

```
[jenkins]
name=Jenkins
baseurl=http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat
gpgcheck=1
```

Then you can use below commands to install jenkins:

```
rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.io.key
yum install jenkins
```

You can also [this](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/) link for more information.